# Bind select react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

https://codesandbox.io/s/dhananjay-rtb8r?file=/src/App.js

Please look sample code. I want to bind city based on state

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.filter() , and then Array.map() to create your sub menu.

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Example :

```js
city.filter(city => city.scopeId === state.id).map(city => <MenuItem {...city} />)
```

**EDIT:**

Hook example:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get('api-url/?state=' + state)
        // for post requests with params , i suggest you use qs library
        // const result = await axios.post('api-url/',qs.stringify({state}))
        return result
    }
    const city = getData()
    setState(oldState => ({...oldState,city}))
},[state])
```

Comment: I think the above is on the right track, you loading extra options from the server and set the state to update the view, react hook form with controller will evaluate user's selection.